# Startup Doomsday Conversation

Tags: management, human-resources

So I am in the weekly meeting with my manager and he tells me if the company (which is a pretty successful startup) is not sold next month, it will shut the doors in three months. I had recently joined, and was having high hopes career and compensation wise. I see them still hiring, I see no other warning signs.

I ask other people, HR, recruiting - they all tell me it would take a long time and be a very drawn out process to shut down, let alone the reputation destruction to the executives and the board.

So a friend of mine, which holds an MBA, tell me that sounds like textbook management tactic to get people engaged, with a sense of urgency. I am really puzzled trying to understand - could that be a management strategy or he is seriously concerned?

Is this really a management strategy? Or does someone want to create friction and have people leave on their own accord? If there is a closure, is there any protection in the law (US) like couple of months severance package?

Comment: Unless there is something specified in your contract, the US is all at will which means you can be fired with no severance or warning.

Comment: @JasonJ Fired yes, but closure may be different.

Comment: @user1220 they can fire you before they Close, can't they?

Comment: @RaoulMensink I don't believe they have a reason to simply fire, that's not what I am concerned about - all my reviews have been excellent. I am concerned with the existence of the company in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, we cannot read your manager's mind.

Comment: You may want to rephrase the question to make it more answerable. You can't expect us to read your manager's mind. However, even if the company is fine and this is a management trick to make you work harder, I'd consider the manager's attitude a red flag and would start looking for work elsewhere.

Comment: I agree, it was a rhetorical question but it doesn't read well. Edited.

Comment: @user1220 they dont need an reason your are subject to at will employment

Comment: @RaoulMensink a single person yes, not so sure about shutting down the entire operation though. Rules seem to be different.

Comment: @user1220 if it wasnt the US I wouldve said yes

Comment: Whether true or not most startups will fail so you need to bear that in mind as the likeliest outcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two most likely explanations are that the company is in financial trouble (update your CV), or the manager is playing mind games to make you word harder (update your CV).

Another possibility is that your manager has found a job elsewhere, and wants to lure good employees to his new company. So if he tells you soon that he's moving elsewhere and there is a job opportunity for you, be very, very careful.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how "If the company is not sold it will be shut down" could be an incentive to work harder. Nothing the average employee can do in the next month will affect whether or not the company is sold, and a manager only needs a tiny bit of brain to know that.